# Erro nesse laço de repetição. Ele só está pegando o primeiro valor do banco de dados

Tags: java, jpa, spring

Erro nesse laço de repetição. Ele só está pegando o primeiro valor do banco de dados. Só está fazendo a consulta no primeiro campo e está ignorando os demais.

```
@Controller
// @RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Autowired
    Usuarios usuarios;


    HttpServletRequest request;
    HttpServletResponse response;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView logins() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/login");
        mv.addObject(new Documento());
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/efetuaLogin")
    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        boolean validacao = false;

        HttpSession sessao;

        List<Usuario> usuariosCadastrados = usuarios.lista();


        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        for (Usuario usuario : usuariosCadastrados) {

            String loginbd = usuario.getUsername();
            String senhabd = usuario.getPassword();

            System.out.println("username do Formulario...:" + loginbd);
            System.out.println("Senha do banco........:" + senhabd);
            System.out.println("Senha do Formulario...:" + password);
            System.out.println("username do Formulario...:" + username);

            if (username.equals(loginbd) && password.equals(senhabd)) {
                validacao = true;

            }
            if (validacao == true) {

                return new ModelAndView("/documentos");

            } else {
                return new ModelAndView("hello");

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

    @Service
public class LoginService {

    @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private Usuarios usuarios; 

    public List<Usuario> lista() {
      return em.createQuery("select u from Usuario u", Usuario.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: O método `lista` da sua classe `LoginService` parece estar certo. Entretanto, o que você traz é o `usuarios.lista()`, da classe `Usuarios` e não da classe `LoginService` (e você não colocou esse método na sua listagem na pergunta, então não dá para dizer o que ou porque está errado). Além disso, você está pegando todos os usuários do banco de dados e olhando um a um para procurar o que tem o login e senha corretos, o que é ineficiente. Seria bem melhor pesquisar no banco de dados só o usuário que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

O motivo de dar errado é a estrutura do seu for. Vamos dar uma olhada:

```
    for (Usuario usuario : usuariosCadastrados) {

        // Várias linhas de código...

        if (validacao == true) {
            return new ModelAndView("/documentos");
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("hello");
        }
    }
    return null;
```

Observe que na primeira iteração, ele irá cair obrigatoriamente ou no `if` ou no `else`, e em ambos os casos, um `return` será executado. Oras, se um `return` será executado sempre na primeira iteração, então ele sempre vai interromper tudo logo na primeira interação.

O que você queria era continuar procurando ao invés de dar um `return` no `else`:

```
    for (Usuario usuario : usuariosCadastrados) {

        String loginbd = usuario.getUsername();
        String senhabd = usuario.getPassword();

        System.out.println("username do Formulario...:" + loginbd);
        System.out.println("Senha do banco........:" + senhabd);
        System.out.println("Senha do Formulario...:" + password);
        System.out.println("username do Formulario...:" + username);

        if (username.equals(loginbd) && password.equals(senhabd)) {
            validacao = true;

        }
        if (validacao == true) {
            return new ModelAndView("/documentos");
        }
    }
    return new ModelAndView("hello");
```

Entretanto, ainda há mais um monte de melhoriaas que podem ser feitas. Usar `== true` por exemplo é totalmente desnecesssário, e a variável se torna desnecesssaria uma vez que ela serve apenas para forçar o fluxo a chegar no `return` logo em seguida. A variável `sessao` também não está sendo usada. Com isso em mente, vamos simplificar seu código ainda mais:

```
@RequestMapping("/efetuaLogin")
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Usuario> usuariosCadastrados = usuarios.lista();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    for (Usuario usuario : usuariosCadastrados) {
        String loginbd = usuario.getUsername();
        String senhabd = usuario.getPassword();
        System.out.println("username do Formulario...:" + loginbd);
        System.out.println("Senha do banco........:" + senhabd);
        System.out.println("Senha do Formulario...:" + password);
        System.out.println("username do Formulario...:" + username);

        if (username.equals(loginbd) && password.equals(senhabd)) {
            return new ModelAndView("/documentos");
        }
    }
    return new ModelAndView("hello");
}
```

Porém, você está pegando todos os usuários do banco de dados e olhando um a um para procurar o que tem o login e senha corretos, o que é ineficiente. Seria bem melhor pesquisar no banco de dados só o usuário que você quer. O banco de dados é o local ideal para realizar este tipo de busca, uma vez que ele tem algoritmos de indexação de dados bastante otimizados para buscas e ao fazer assim você também reduz significativamente o volume de dados trafegado entre o banco de dados e a aplicação, o que também melhora o desempenho e o cosumo de memória. Assim sendo, o seu `LoginService` fica assim:

```
@Service
public class LoginService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private Usuarios usuarios; 

    public Usuario logar(String login, String senha) {
        try {
            return em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.username = :login AND u.password = :senha", Usuario.class)
                    .setParameter("login", login)
                    .setParameter("senha", senha)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Seu método de login fica assim:

```
@RequestMapping("/efetuaLogin")
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Usuario> usuariosCadastrados = usuarios.lista();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Usuario usuario = usuarios.logar(username, password)';
    if (usuario != null) return new ModelAndView("/documentos");
    return new ModelAndView("hello");
}
```

Além disso, você está trazendo os dados do banco de dados, por meio da classe `Usuarios` e não por meio da classe `LoginService`. Entretanto, você não colocou o código da classe `Usuarios` na sua pergunta, então não dá para dizer se lá tudo está certo ou não. Entretanto, uma vez que agora você está usando um método novo para pesquisar no banco de dados, a classe `Usuarios` também terá que ser alterada.

E para terminar, vamos ver o resto da sua controller:

Ela herda de `HttpServlet`, o que sugere que uma única instância desta classe será criada e compartilhada por todas as requisições. Entretanto, você colocou os métodos `setPassword`, `getPassword`, `setUsername`, `getUsername` e os campos `username`, `password`, `request` e `response`, todos eles são específicos para cada requisição em particular. O resultado disso será ruim, pois você está colocando em um lugar compartilhado entre todas as requisições, dados que pertencem a cada requisição individualmente, e assim se duas requisições usarem estes métodos e campos simultaneamente o resultado será desastroso.

Para resolver esse problema, simplesmente delete tais métodos e campos, pois eles são desnecessários uma vez que os dados referentes a eles que você possa precisar já estão no seu método `login`.